# Conditional Bulk Connection <>

Tags: chisel

I would like to do a conditional bulk connection of bidirectional buses, conceptually like the following.

```
val io = IO(new Bundle {
  val master = Decoupled(UInt(8.W))
  val slave0 = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
  val slave1 = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
  val select = Input(Bool())
})

when (select) {
  io.slave0 <> io.master
  io.slave1 <> some_null_decoupled
}.otherwise {
  io.slave1 <> io.master
  io.slave0 <> some_null_decoupled
}
```

This is cleaner than having to individually describe the logic for the `io.master.ready`, `io.slave0.bits`, `io.slave0.valid`, ... etc signals.

Is there a syntax similar to this which will work? When I try this in my code, I get a lot of `firrtl.passes.CheckInitialization$RefNotInitializedException` messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with the description of `some_null_decoupled`. That looks sane other than the fact that `some_null_decoupled` is missing. The following works fine for me (using Chisel 3.1.6):

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._

class ConditionalBulkConnect extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val master = Decoupled(UInt(8.W))
    val slave0 = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
    val slave1 = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
    val select = Input(Bool())
  })

  val some_null_decoupled = Wire(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
  some_null_decoupled.ready := false.B

  when (io.select) {
    io.slave0 <> io.master
    io.slave1 <> some_null_decoupled
  }.otherwise {
    io.slave1 <> io.master
    io.slave0 <> some_null_decoupled
  }
}

object ConditionalBulkConnectTop extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new ConditionalBulkConnect)
}
```

Does this help at all? Otherwise can you provide more information, like the implementation of `some_null_decoupled` and version of Chisel?

Comment: This is super helpful - works for me too. I mostly wanted to know if it _should_ be possible. My real example that I was working on has complicated bundles as I/O, so probably I was just configuring the null value incorrectly. Now that I know this works I can debug my module.